# Notation regarding a set with two disjoint properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm trying to write the solution to the following equation in set builder notation
$$\max\{|x_1|,|x_2| \}=1$$ So far, I've come up with:

$$\big\{ (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \big(|x_1|=1, -1\le x_2 \le 1\big) \vee \big(|x_2|=1, -1\le x_1 \le 1\big)\big\}$$
Is this correct? I'd like to be able to write it properly, like the way it would ideally be written but this seem a little shaky to me.

Comment: What's wrong with $$\{(x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}: \max\{|x_1|, |x_2|\}=1\}$$?

Comment: I'm trying to solve a problem where this kinda notation is an intermediary step in showing the solution is actually the coordinates of a square. I kinda need to write it similar to the way I tried to make things a little clearer.

Comment: @NeelanshGuptaa yes this is correct, I would however replace the commata with $\land$ for more precise notation.